# SQL How to join multiplue columns with same name to one column

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a super class

- account {User, TYPE}

and subclasses

- saving{User, ID, balance,TYPE,interest,curency_TYPE}
- time{User,ID,balance,TYPE,interest,curency_TYPE,start_date,due_date,period}
- fore{User,ID,balance,interest,curency_TYPE}

User and TYPE is the primary key of account and foreign key of three subclasses
ID is primary key of three subclasses

how to make a list of showing all IDs in one column?Also the same as balance and TYPE meet the problem

I considered `a.ID as saving, b.ID as time` but it showing them separately

Comment: can you explain more? how about using `CONCAT` or `GROUP_CONCAT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, `UNION ALL` is what you need:

```
SELECT ID, balance, TYPE FROM saving
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, balance, TYPE FROM time
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, balance, TYPE FROM fore;
```